# Restrict records top 5 entity dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

How do I restrict records in a entity dataset to say five records. I have to list best sellers but I want to show only five at a time?

i.e does it have a row count variable that I can set?

```
     <asp:EntityDataSource ID="entybestseller" runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="name=CommerceEntities" 
          DefaultContainerName="CommerceEntities"  AutoGenerateWhereClause=true
        EnableFlattening="False" 
          EntitySetName="products">
          <WhereParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="isBestSeller" DefaultValue="True" DbType=Boolean />
          </WhereParameters>
      </asp:EntityDataSource>

      <asp:ListView ID="lvbestseller"  runat="server" DataSourceID="entybestseller">

      <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="s_item grid_2"> <a class="s_thumb" href="#"><img src="images/dummy/pic_5.jpg" title="Armani Acqua di Gioia" alt="Armani Acqua di Gioia" /></a>
      <h3><a href="#"><%# Eval("title") %> </a></h3>
      <p class="s_model"><%# Eval("title") %></p>
      <p class="s_price s_promo_price"><span class="s_old_price"><span class="s_currency s_before"> <span><%# Eval("listprice") %></span><span class="s_currency s_before"></span><%# Eval("salesprice") %></p>
      <a class="s_button_add_to_cart" href="addtocart.aspx?productid=<%# Eval("id") %>"><span class="s_icon_16"><span class="s_icon"></span>Add to Cart</span></a>
    </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a select Attribute to your EntityDataSource

```
select="select top(5) title, id, listprice, salesprice"
```

That should do the trick.